# sshd: error: connect_to ff00::: unknown host

Tags: ssh, ipv6, socks5-proxy

when I connect to server with ssh with SOCKS proxy tunnel, ie:

```
ssh myserver -D2345
```

and then on the cleint start firefox and configure SOKS proxy to use my tunnel, then on the server, I get flood of following errors in the logs:

```
sshd: error: connect_to ff00::: unknown host (Address family for hostname not supported)
```

this looks like someone is trying to resolve IPv6 address, but I don't have IPv6 support neither on the server, nor on the client that I am connecting from.

My kernel does not have IPv6 at all.

How can I disable anything related to IPv6 so that I don't get these errors ?

On my server, I have clearly specificaly configured only IPv4 addreses in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
AddressFamily inet
ListenAddress 10.20.30.40
```